# Audio manipulation using HTML 5/JavaScript/possibly flash?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio

Are there any libraries that allow you to take audio as an input and allow you to manipulate the sound on the client side (browser)?

We are exploring the idea of audio being played locally or remotely and a user can manipulate the source, i.e pitch, tempo etc

Ideally looking for a HTML 5 / JavaScript library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood you correctly this should be possible with the HTML5 Audio API.

Take a look at this:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/?redirect_from_locale=de

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Great, this pretty much answers the question.  Will research to see if we can achieve our audio goals using the filters available.